# focus is working as click in firefox and edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility

I'm trying to set focus on one element when we click on some button. working fine in chrome.

```
$("#element").find('li').first().find('a').get(0).focus();
```

tried with setTimeout as well.

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $("#element").find('li').first().find('a').get(0).focus();
},10);
```

code works fine in chrome and not working in firefox and edge. can you please help me to make it works across all the browsers.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: What is "_not working_" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Chrome, FX, Edge

Firefox does not put a border but does focus

```js
$('#element li:first a').focus();
```

```css
a:focus { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="element">
 <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
</ul>
```